# A planar graph G, seek the upper bound of the size of m of B with the big O notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Let A be the set of vertices of a planar graph G, B the smallest set of colors such that each vertex can be assigned to a color in R and no two adjacent colors are assigned to the same color, seek the upper bound of the size of m of B with the big O notation. The bound shall be as tight as possible.

Would the answer be O(2^n)? I don't know. I am not very familiar with this type of tasks and wonder where I shall start to solve a task like this? I roughly read Computational Geometry, Data structures, and algorithms, GIS - A Computing Perspective. But I couldn't get my head around it. Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *"no two adjacent colors are assigned to the same color"*: I don't understand this phrase. Do you mean "no two adjacent vertices"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @trincot yes, I think you are right, the vertices color.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sorry, I wasn't sure which forum to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found, you want smallest number of color for planar graphs vertex coloring. There is a theorem which is called [Four Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). It says all planar graphs can be colored by 4 colors.

Moreover, you can check [Five Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_color_theorem) too. Hence `|B| = O(1)` and not related to the number of vertices of the planar graph.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge.